Is Acts 21:8 indicating that Philip was (earlier) one of the seven or that he was (still) actively one of the seven, feeding widows?
On Paul's return from the third missionary journey he comes to Caesarea Maritima:

8 On the next day we departed and came to Caesarea, and we entered the house of Philip the evangelist, who was one of the seven, and stayed with him. (Acts 21:8 ESV)

In Greek: Φιλίππου τοῦ εὐαγγελιστοῦ ὄντος ἐκ τῶν ἑπτὰ
I'm not as good with my Greek participles. Is this saying that he was earlier one of the seven or that he was still one of the seven? It seems odd that here we are all these years later and Philip might still be designated as a deacon (to "serve tables" per Acts 6:2), serving the widows, when he's not even in Jerusalem anymore.
If he's no longer an active serving-the-widows deacon, per his assignment in Acts 6:5, then did the whole serving-the-widows arrangement get dissolved at the time that Saul started ravaging the church in Jerusalem, when everyone was "scattered throughout the regions of Judea and Samaria, except the apostles" (Acts 8:1)? Such that, when Philip headed off into Samaria as an evangelist (8:4-5), he no longer had the deacon designation, at least in the serving-the-widows sense? I'd never connected the dots, that this feeding the widows activity only lasted for a couple years.
But perhaps this explains the emphasis in James, which exhorts the Jewish Christians "in the dispersion" (James 1:1-2) to be looking after (ἐπισκέπτεσθαι) the widows (James 1:27), since the deacons in Jerusalem were no longer doing so.
Back to the question: Is Acts 21:8 indicating that Philip was (earlier) one of the seven or that he was (still) actively one of the seven, feeding widows?

The way the OP presents the quote that makes it look like a genitive absolute, but it's a present tense genitive participle:-
Τῇ δὲ ἐπαύριον ἐξελθόντες ἤλθομεν εἰς Καισάρειαν, καὶ εἰσελθόντες εἰς τὸν οἶκον Φιλίππου τοῦ εὐαγγελιστοῦ ὄντος ἐκ τῶν ἑπτὰ ἐμείναμεν παρ’ αὐτῷ.
The house of Philip the evangelist being from the seven.
For this see:-
https://archive.org/details/agreekgrammarfo02smytgoog/page/454/mode/2up
The tenses of the participle (except the future) not in indirect discourse are timeless, and denote only stage of action (1852). When they stand in indirect discourse and represent the indicative, they denote time relatively to that of the main verb.
As usual with English questions of Greek participles, the question doesn't really arise. He is currently being one of the seven people who were appointed deacons before. This is why translations are adding a past tense. It doesn't necessarily mean he is still in the rank of deacon, or even still among the seven. The group is mentally re-constituted for the participle's real purpose of clarifying which Philip we're talking about, and he is then selected (ἐκ=from or out of) from it. (And the ἐκ doesn't create a hard converse such that he's definitely no longer a member of the group or a deacon.)

A briefly-perceived Genitive Absolute?
It might have sounded to listeners like it was going to be a genitive absolute.
https://archive.org/details/agreekgrammarfo02smytgoog/page/458/mode/2up
Really all that makes this unnatural is that the house hasn't been mentioned before - and that's largely our language's tendency to over-emphasize Greek's definite article.
Remembering words are read or heard in sequence, the reader/listener might be having to re-arrange their understanding on the hoof:-
καὶ εἰσελθόντες εἰς τὸν οἶκον Φιλίππου...
[illustration-not-translation] and having gone into the house of Philip...
καὶ εἰσελθόντες εἰς τὸν οἶκον Φιλίππου τοῦ εὐαγγελιστοῦ ὄντος
[illustration-not-translation] and having gone into the house, (Philip being an evangelist)
καὶ εἰσελθόντες εἰς τὸν οἶκον Φιλίππου τοῦ εὐαγγελιστοῦ ὄντος ἐκ τῶν ἑπτὰ ἐμείναμεν παρ’ αὐτῷ
[illustration-not-translation] Having gone into the house of Philip the evangelist (being from the seven), we stayed with him.
Luke (or the author) could have used the same construction as English, which is to split it out into a relative clause: ὃς ἐκ τῶν ἑπτὰ ἦν, which would have got round the ambiguity at the expense of being bitty and having an ἦ in assonance with two ἐs. But I only mention this because sometimes this sort of thing is worth counting as evidence for whether the work was read on the page or recited.

Good insight! The preposition is the key. I accept that the ἐκ doesn't create a hard converse, yet it does establish a sense of remoteness which the English "was one of the seven" does not adequately convey--for me at least!

Here is my literal translation of Acts 21:8 -

Now, on the next day, having gone forth, we came to Caesarea; and
having entered into the house of Philip the evangelist, being of the
seven, we stayed with him.

Note the verb ὄντος ("being") suggests that Philip is one of the seven deacons as appointed in Acts 6:1-6.  The tense of the participle is present active which indicates that it is an on-going action; that is, Philip is, and continues to be, one of the seven deacons.
